# Why the Cascading persist does not work with many-to-many relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many, cascade

Please look at the following code snippets from 2 classes (Entities) `Student` and `Course`

```java
public class Student {
   ...

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "course_student",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="course_id")
   )
   private List<Course> courses;
   
   ...
}
    
public class Course {
   ...
   
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "course_student",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="course_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
   )
   private List<Student> students;
   
   ...
}
```

and the driver code is as follows

```java
try {
    session.beginTransaction();
    Course course = new Course("Ukulele master class");
    Student student1 = new Student("Jishnu","M V","jishnumv@gmail.com");
    Student student2 = new Student("Praveen","M V","praveenmv@gmail.com");
    course.add(student1);
    course.add(student2);
    session.save(course);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

When I run this code I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.jithin.entity.Student
```

So my doubt is. **persisting the Course does not persist the associated Student(s) even though we have mentioned CascadeType.ALL in the Course class. So why the cascading is not working in the case of many to many?**

nb: When I saved both the student objects using `session.save()`, before saving the course object. There were no exception.

Comment: What do you mean by *Nb: The code works perfectly When I saved the students as well.*?

Comment: I mean when I saved both the student objects using session.save() before saving the course object. There were no exception.

Comment: @jithinMV You have `courses` inside `Course`?

Comment: @SternK Oh I am sorry, the code wasn't edited correctly. It is now updated. Thank you  for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `@JoinTable` annotation only on the owning side of the `@ManyToMany` association.

```java
@Entity
public class Student {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "course_student",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="course_id"))
    private List<Course> courses;
   
   // ...
}

@Entity
public class Course {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Student> students;

   // ...
}
```

2. If you use bidirectional association you should take care about synchronization of both sides of association. So, you should add the following methods to your `Course` entity:

```java
public class Course {

  public void addStudent(Student student) {
     students.add(student);
     student.getCourses().add( this );
  }

  public void removeStudent(Student student) {
     students.remove(student);
     student.getCourses().remove( this );
  }

  // ...
}
```

and then you will be able to do something like this:

```java
Course course = new Course("Ukulele master class");
Student student1 = new Student("Jishnu","M V","jishnumv@gmail.com");
Student student2 = new Student("Praveen","M V","praveenmv@gmail.com");
course.addStudent(student1);
course.addStudent(student2);
session.save(course);
```

3. As it mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many):

> For `@ManyToMany` associations, the `REMOVE` entity state transition doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the link table. Since the other side might be referenced by other entities on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a `ConstraintViolationException`.

That is why you should avoid to use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in the `@ManyToMany`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried the code you mentioned. But it is only saving the Course to the database, but still It doesn't save the associated students of the course via cascading.

Comment: It should work. Did you use exactly the same mapping including helper methods as it mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did. And I found something while browsing the same issue. When we use session.save() the cascading happens in SAVE_UPDATE cascade type which is under hibernate. Not within JPA.  So either we have to add CascadeType. ALL and use session.save() or we have to use session.persist() instead. Anyway the former one is not a good practice because as you said it will also include REMOVE so we can go with the later one and it worked as well

Comment: Maybe it depends on hibernate version. I have tested this mapping with further `session.save(course)` and it works with Hibernate 5.4.10.Final